# FetchXML doesn't return aggregate column when null values encountered

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I have a FetchXML query that reuturns two aggregate columns:

```
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'>
  <entity name='blocktrade'>
    <attribute name='sourceref' alias='trade_count' aggregate='count'/>
    <attribute name='allocationtradecount' alias='alloc' aggregate='sum'/>
    <attribute name='organisation' alias='org' groupby='true'/>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

If I restrict the query to return objects that have values in allocationtradecount it works as expected. However, if some objects have null for the allocationtradecount, the column is not returned in the results!

i.e.

```
(int)((AliasedValue)e["alloc_count"]).Value;
```

fails. Is this 'expected'? How can I ensure 0 is used when null values are summed?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: same problem here please help

Comment: Sorry, I abandoned this approach. :(

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to first check whether that record contains any value.

Like shown in following code...
Consider, you want to assign value to int sum.

```
int sum = e.Attributes.Contains("alloc") ? (int)((AliasedValue)e["alloc"]).Value : 0;
```

Above code first check whether record contains any value if yes it will return sum else it will return 0.

Hope this helps.